# Adding PUT/DELETE to Ruby WEBrick

Tags: ruby, webrick

I'm trying to add PUT and DELETE verbs to WEBrick.  I don't need them to do anything.  They just need to respond with a 200.  Below is the script I am running.  GET works, but DELETE returns 405 with a "unsupported method DELETE" message.  Can anyone tell me what is wrong or missing with this code?

```
require 'webrick'

module WEBrick
  module HTTPServlet
    class ProcHandler
      alias do_PUT    do_GET
      alias do_DELETE do_GET
    end
  end
end

sRoot = "C:\\"

server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new :Port => 8000, :DocumentRoot => sRoot

trap "INT" do server.shutdown end

server.start
```

Comment: You probably need to add PUT and DELETE to some list of allowed methods. Grep the source for "unsupported method".

Comment: That's an odd thing to do. Why Webrick and not something that was updated in the last ten years? Don't [Unicorn](http://unicorn.bogomips.org/) and [Thin](https://github.com/macournoyer/thin/) do this properly?

Comment: @tadman, webrick comes installed with Ruby.  We don't need this for serving up actual web pages.  Just as a simple HTTP endpoint for some very simple tests.  Webrick wins in this case because it requires zero installation across the machines that will be using it.

Comment: That's just a minor advantage in terms of not having any dependencies, yet it's a massive disadvantage because it's barely functional by today's standards. If you can write your entire application without using one external dependency, that's interesting but highly unusual.

Comment: The script in this question (which by the way was "how do I get this working?") *is* the application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out.  I had to add appropriate handlers to DefaultFileHandler.  @kimmo, thanks for the tip!

```
require 'webrick'

module WEBrick
  module HTTPServlet
    class FileHandler
      alias do_PUT    do_GET
      alias do_DELETE do_GET
    end

    class DefaultFileHandler
      def do_DELETE(req, res)
        res.body = ''
      end

      def do_PUT(req, res)
        res.body = ''
      end
    end
  end
end

sRoot = "C:\\"

server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new :Port => 8000, :DocumentRoot => sRoot

trap "INT" do server.shutdown end

server.start
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. Which version of Ruby does this work on?

Answer (score 3):

Looking at [Rack's WEBrick implementation](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/f4fa3af01c0d796ee414af6691bdd64e6615ec77/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb#L58) is also informative.

Rack overrides the [`WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet#service` method](http://ruby-doc.org//stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/webrick/rdoc/WEBrick/HTTPServlet/AbstractServlet.html#method-i-service).

An example:

```
require 'webrick'

class TestServer < WEBrick::HTTPServlet::AbstractServlet
  def service(request, response)
    response.body = "#{request.request_method}:\n\t" +
      "#{request.inspect.lines.to_a.join("\t")}"
  end
end

server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new Port: 8000
server.mount '/', TestServer
trap 'INT' do server.shutdown end
server.start
```

---

```
curl -X DELETE localhost:8000
```

gives

```
DELETE:
  DELETE / HTTP/1.1
  User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
  Host: localhost:8000
  Accept: */*
```

Comment: instead if def service, i used def do_GET, and created alias for do_POST,do_PUT and do_DELETE pointing it

Answer (score 1):

Kent's answer didn't work for me...perhaps WEBrick has been updated...

But it did give me the clues.

```
  module HTTPServlet
    class ProcHandler
      alias do_PUT    do_GET
      alias do_DELETE do_GET
    end
  end

  @server = WEBrick::HTTPServer.new( config )
  @server.mount_proc '/' do | req, res |
    ...
  end

  @server.start
```

ruby 2.2.3p173